# How to rewrite www.mysite.com/au to www.mysite.au

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I have a main site setup for multiple countries. For example, I have -

Australian site - [www.mysite.com/au](http://www.mysite.com/au) 
UK site - [www.mysite.com/uk](http://www.mysite.com/uk)

How can a request for [www.mysite.au](http://www.mysite.au) point to the /au domain? For example, a request like [www.mysite.au/about](http://www.mysite.au/about) should resolve to [www.mysite.com/au/about](http://www.mysite.com/au/about) and should show [www.mysite.au/about](http://www.mysite.au/about) in the URL.

This is setup in IIS/Azure, so I like to see the rule to do this in the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, when you go to a URL like `www.mysite.au/about` in the address bar of your browser, the content of the `www.mysite.com/au/about` page will be displayed. To achieve this, you need to use Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite and Application Request Routing. The specific implementation steps are as follows:

1. You need to enable reverse proxy in IIS. If you have not installed the ARR module, you need to download and install it first.

[image]

[image]

2. Take your description as an example, you need to have a site with the host name [www.mysite.au](http://www.mysite.au) in IIS as a reverse proxy site, and then you need to add a reverse proxy rewrite rule under this site.

reverse proxy rule in web.config

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
       <rule name="rule for reverse proxy">
           <match url="(.*)" />
           <conditions>
               <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.mysite.(.*)" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.my site.com/{C:1}/{R:1}" />
       </rule>
     </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Through the above reverse proxy settings, when you access `www.mysite.au/about`,the request will be forwarded to `www.mysite.com/au/about`.

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing) to learn more about Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite and ARR.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me how to achieve this in azure? Sorry that I didn't mention it in my original post [I will try to add that detail]. Since I can't get to IIS settings, this should be a bit different there.

Mine is an azure web app, and www.<mysite>.com is a LIVE, production site as well. Any settings I add here shouldn't hurt that site at all.

Comment: You need to add azure related tags to locate the problem to the correct scope.